# Evaluating a Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a physics problem, but my question is a mathematics one. I am wondering how to calculate the partition function of a quantum particle in a 1D infinite square well. The energy of an energy level is $E_n = \frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL^2}$. I found the partition function to be

$$Z = \bigg[\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \bigg( \frac{1}{e^{\pi^2 \hbar^2/ 2mL^2k_B T}}\bigg)^{n^2}\bigg] - 1.$$

Is there a closed form formula for this series, assuming convergence? It is sort of like a geometric one, but isn't.

Comment: Ignoring all of the excessive notation, you ask how to evaluate the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2}$?  It doesn't come up very often, but you can express the result using the [Theta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) if you insist.  That function isn't particularly convenient to work with however, so it may not be helpful.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JMoravitz commented,
$$Z(x)=\sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^{n^2}-1=\frac{1}{2} (\vartheta _3(0,x)-1)$$ From a practical point of view, we can make quite reasonable approximations using Padé approximants. One we used is
$$Z(x)=\frac {x(1+2x^3+x^6) } {1+x^3-x^8 }$$ which is quite good for $0 \leq x \leq \frac 12$. At the upper bound, the maximum error is $8.5 \times 10^{-6}$.